# "must be a real number, not NoneType" when trying if/else syntax to return a user input

Tags: python

I'm not sure what I'm doing, though I admit I'm new to Python. The idea is to just get a user input for the spring constant, and if it's greater than 0 use it in the equation, if not keep prompting until you get one greater than 0. I'm getting the error "TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType" and I really don't understand why. The only explanation I can find is that I'm recursively calling the function inside an if/else branch, which somehow returns a non-float?

```
# This program prints the frequency of a spring-mass system given user inputs

import math

# defining the constants
constant = 1/(2*math.pi) # 1/2pi
mass = 10 # mass of the object

def get_constant():
    spring_constant = float(input("Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): "))
    if spring_constant >= 0:
        return spring_constant
    else:
        print("Please enter a non-negative number.")
        get_constant()

print("The frequency is:",constant*(math.sqrt(get_constant())/mass))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should return the function in your `else` branch:

   ```
   else:
       print("Please enter a non-negative number.")
       return get_constant()
   ```
2. You should put the input reader line to a `try/excep block`. You can validate the input with it (If it is a valid number). If the input cannot be convert to float (so not a number), a `ValueError` exception will be raised.

   ```
   try:
       spring_constant = float(input("Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): "))
   except ValueError:
       print("Please provide a valid number")
       return get_constant()
   ```

**Complete code:**

```
import math

# defining the constants
constant = 1/(2*math.pi) # 1/2pi
mass = 10 # mass of the object

def get_constant():
    try:
        spring_constant = float(input("Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please provide a valid number")
        return get_constant()
    if spring_constant >= 0:
        return spring_constant
    else:
        print("Please enter a non-negative number.")
        return get_constant()

print("The frequency is:",constant*(math.sqrt(get_constant())/mass))
```

**Tests:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): asdf
Please provide a valid number
Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): 5
The frequency is: 0.03558812717085886

>>> python3 test.py 
Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): -1
Please enter a non-negative number.
Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): 5   
The frequency is: 0.03558812717085886

>>-> python3 test.py 
Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): asd
Please provide a valid number
Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): -2
Please enter a non-negative number.
Please enter the spring constant in N/m (a non-negative number): 5
The frequency is: 0.03558812717085886
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I edited the else branch to
return get_constant()
which solved it. I guess it was just running the function over and over and needed a call to return the value.

Comment: Note: this will also crash if you type in something that isn't a number (e.g. "foo")